# SQL Server FOR JSON: Query a list of values and use the first two characters as a key in json object

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a table with about 900,000 rows. One of the columns has a 7 character value that I need to search for client-side validation of user input. I'm currently using ajax as the user types, but most of the users can out-run the ajax round trips and end up having to wait until the all the validation calls return. So I want to shift the wait time to the initial load of the app and take advantage of browser caching. So I'll bundle minify and gzip the json file with webpack. I'll probably make it an entry that I can then require/ensure as the app loads.

To make the validation super fast on the client side I want to produce a json file that has a single json structure with the first two characters of the 7 character column as the key to the object with an array of all values that start with the first two characters as an array in the value for said key (see example below). I can then use indexOf to find the value within this segmented list and it will be very quick.

As mentioned above I'm currently using ajax as the user types.

I'm not going to show my code because it's too complex. But I basically keep track of the pending ajax requests and when the request that started with the last value the user entered returns (the value currently sitting in the text box), then I can show the user if the entry exists or not. That way if the request return out of order, I'm not giving false positives.

I'm using SQL Server 2016 so I want to use `for json` to produce my desired output. But here's what I want to produce:

```
{
    "00": [ "0000001", "0000002", ... ],
    "10": [ "1000000", "1000001", ... ],
    //...
    "99": [ "9900000", "9900001", ...]
}
```

So far I have been unable to figure out how to use `substring( mySevenDigitCol, 1, 2 )` as the key in the json object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be done using `FOR JSON AUTO` (`["0000001", "0000002", ... ]` is the difficult part), but next approach based on string manipulation is one possible solution to your problem:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   SevenDigitColumn varchar(7)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (SevenDigitColumn)
VALUES
   ('0000001'),
   ('0000002'),
   ('0000003'),
   ('0000004'),
   ('0000005'),
   ('1000001'),
   ('1000002'),
   ('9900001'),
   ('9900002')
```

T-SQL:

```
;WITH JsonData AS (
   SELECT 
      SUBSTRING(dat.SevenDigitColumn, 1, 2) AS [Key],
      agg.StringAgg AS [Values]
   FROM #Data dat
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT STUFF(
         (
         SELECT CONCAT(',"', SevenDigitColumn, '"')
         FROM #Data
         WHERE SUBSTRING(SevenDigitColumn, 1, 2) = SUBSTRING(dat.SevenDigitColumn, 1, 2)
         FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, '') AS StringAgg
      ) agg
   GROUP BY SUBSTRING(dat.SevenDigitColumn, 1, 2), agg.StringAgg
)

SELECT CONCAT(
   '{',
   STUFF(
      (
      SELECT CONCAT(',"', [Key], '": [', [Values], ']')
      FROM JsonData
      FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1,  1, ''),
   '}')
```

Output:

```
{"00": ["0000001","0000002","0000003","0000004","0000005"],"10": ["1000001","1000002"],"99": ["9900001","9900002"]}
```

Notes:
With SQL Server 2017+ you can use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT(
      '{',
      STRING_AGG(KeyValue, ','),
      '}'
   )
FROM (   
   SELECT CONCAT(
      '"',
      SUBSTRING(dat.SevenDigitColumn, 1, 2),
      '": [',
      STRING_AGG('"' + SevenDigitColumn + '"', ','),
      ']'
   ) AS KeyValue  
   FROM #Data dat
   GROUP BY SUBSTRING(dat.SevenDigitColumn, 1, 2)
) JsonData
```

Notes:

If your column data is not only digits, you should use [STRING_ESCAPE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with `'json'` as second parameter to escape special characters.